# How to specify ApplicationCertificate using OPC foundation (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, opc-ua

The certificate I am using (client2.p12) isn't recognized when in program data.
The path to my certificate is:

`C:\ProgramData\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault\client2.p12`

I manually made this path.

I can use the certificate if I use this code and put the certificate in a folder with the code:

```
var appCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @".\certs\client2.p12"), "123");

config.SecurityConfig.ApplicationCertificate = new(appCertificate);
```

What I want is this:

```
ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier
{
    StoreType = "Directory",
    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault",
    SubjectName = "client2.p12"
    //or this? SubjectName = "O=Siemens, C=DE, CN=Siemens TIA Project(4JGMmGiXXkylgtqHpIhfvg)"
},
```

The Error I am getting: ApplicationCertificate cannot be found

I put the certificate in the place previous mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: Error could be cause because you cannot read the file (or path).  Are you running from inside VS or running the exe file?  When inside VS you do not have admn unless you start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the note about running it as admin, unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** There is an easier way to specify (and create if needed during runtime) your certificate, I made another answer in **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75720196/how-does-certificate-identification-work-in-opc-foundation-net-sdk/75833881#75833881)**

*The things below are not the easiest way and are quite bad. You can still use this for other purposes.*

I believe I expected some wrong things. To use a existing certificate you can use ( below is another version):

```
var appCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @".\certs\client2.p12"), "123");
application.ApplicationConfiguration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate = new(appCertificate);
```

So if I want to use the path from ProgramData I can just use the path that I used in my answer

Now if you don't have a certificate and want to make one during runtime you can use this:

Your  `config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate` can be somethings like this:

```
ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier
{
    StoreType = "Directory",
    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault",
    SubjectName = "O=company, C=NL, CN=MyClientCert"
},
```

Same if you use in a XML file

To get your local ips and dns for the certificate you are going to make:

```
private static List<string> GetLocalIpAddressAndDns()
    {
        List<string> localIps = new List<string>();
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIps.Add(ip.ToString());
            }
        }
        if (localIps.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        }
        localIps.Add(Dns.GetHostName());
        return localIps;
    }
```

Now you can make a certificate and insert it into your configuration:

```
// Get local interface ip addresses and DNS name
List<string> localIps = GetLocalIpAddressAndDns();
UInt16 keySize = 2048; //must be multiples of 1024
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
string certPassword = "123";
UInt16 lifeTime = 2048;
UInt16 hashSize = 2048;

// Make certificate
config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate = new(CertificateFactory.CreateCertificate(
     config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StoreType,
     config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StorePath,
     certPassword,
     config.ApplicationUri,
     config.ApplicationName,
     config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.SubjectName,
     localIps,
     keySize,
     startTime,
     lifeTime,
     hashSize
));
```

It now generates a certificate everytime you run this code

EDIT: To get the saved certificate you made with the previous code:

```
config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.LoadPrivateKey("123").Wait();

config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate = new(config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Find(true).Result);
```