# How does certificate identification work in OPC foundation .net sdk

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, opc-ua

I need to use a custom certificate in my OPC client. I made this client in .net with the opc ua client sdk.

Currently I can make a certificate in the program using this code:

```
// Get local interface ip addresses and DNS name
List<string> localIps = GetLocalIpAddressAndDns();
UInt16 keySize = 2048; //must be multiples of 1024
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
string certPassword = "123";
UInt16 lifeTime = 24;
UInt16 hashSize = 2048;    

//Make ApplicationCertificate from xml settings
    config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate = new(CertificateFactory.CreateCertificate(
       config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StoreType,
       config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StorePath,
       certPassword,
       config.ApplicationUri,
       config.ApplicationName,
       config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.SubjectName,
       localIps,
       keySize,
       startTime,
       lifeTime,
       hashSize
       ));
```

After this I can use this certificate I just made by using this code:

```
config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.LoadPrivateKey("123").Wait();
config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate = new(config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Find(true).Result);
//config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Find(true)
```

I just made a certificate with openSSL that is the same as the generated certificate but it can't find it (I deleted the generated certificate).

Don't mind the names I used a tutorial from opc publisher to make the certificates and didn't changes the names/uri

Generated by the program certificate (this one can be found):

[image: cert]

[image: cert2]

This is the certificate generated by openSSL (this one cannot be find):

[image: cert3]

[image: cert4]

My XML settings:

```
<ApplicationName>opcpublisher</ApplicationName>

    <ApplicationUri>urn:desktop-q2t5j2p:Microsoft.Azure.IIoT:microsoft</ApplicationUri>
    
    <ProductUri>urn:SIMATIC.S7-1200.OPC-UA.Application:StratusPLC</ProductUri>
    <ApplicationType>Client_1</ApplicationType>

    <SecurityConfiguration>
        <ApplicationCertificate>
            <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
            <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault</StorePath>
            <SubjectName>CN=opcpublisher, O=mycompany</SubjectName>
        </ApplicationCertificate>
```

I believe the methode find() finds the certificate by matching the SubjectName, but my subjectname is the same and it still doens't work. I also tried using thumbprint.

[image: error]

How do I make my code get the certificate from openSSL using the find() methode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out how I can identify a certificate using opc foundation .net:

This is the certificate I use but made for another project:

[image]

```
SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
{
    ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = "opcpublisher" },
    TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
    TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
    RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
    AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
    AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true
},
```

and this will create/find certificate on runtime based on the ApplicationCertificate above:

```
application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Using the CN (CN = opcpublisher) at the place of SubjectName (SubjectName = "opcpublisher") it identifies the certificate I want to use!
Using an other SubjectName will result in a creation of a new certificate.

edit: you can also do this:

```
ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = "CN=OPCUA Client, C=US, S=Arizona, O=OPC Foundation, DC=localhost" },
```